# VBA how to use * as a character and not wildcard for cell.formula like

Tags: excel, character, wildcard, vba

I am trying to write an `If` statement to differentiate between formulas with `"=100*..."` and `"=1000*..."` with the `*` being a multiplier not a wildcard.

Ex.
`If (Cell.Formula Like "=100*") = True Then ...`

however both cases are deemed true. Also I tried

`If (Cell.Formula Like "=100~*") = True Then` and it didn't work. How do I get the asterisk to be used as a multiply sign

Answer (score 1):

Use the [InStr function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8460tsh1.aspx).

```
if cbool(instr(1, cell.formula, "=100*", vbbinarycompare))) then
```